# Winsorize data with inf values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, scipy

I have the following data:

```
{'Date': {0: Timestamp('2016-05-10 00:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('2016-05-11 00:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('2016-05-12 00:00:00'), 3: Timestamp('2016-05-13 00:00:00'), 4: Timestamp('2016-05-14 00:00:00'), 5: Timestamp('2016-05-15 00:00:00'), 6: Timestamp('2016-05-16 00:00:00'), 7: Timestamp('2016-05-17 00:00:00'), 8: Timestamp('2016-05-18 00:00:00'), 9: Timestamp('2016-05-19 00:00:00'), 10: Timestamp('2016-05-20 00:00:00'), 11: Timestamp('2016-05-21 00:00:00')}, 'variable': {0: 0.8491095654077778, 1: 0.40413794873666165, 2: 0.21376796260531072, 3: 0.07286348591835323, 4: 0.5721419081310215, 5: 0.35390011440489355, 6: 0.010530093815129149, 7: 0.013325613826142724, 8: 0.9207323422142153, 9: inf, 10: 0.5726367316365334, 11: 0.8351572257132013}}
```

I would like to winsorize it, so I tried:

```
df_inf['variable'] = winsorize(df_inf['variable'], limits=[0.05, 0.05], inclusive=(True, True), inplace=False, axis=None, nan_policy='omit')
```

However, the inf value is not replaced. Any ideas on how winsorizing can be applied to the inf value as well?

Comment: Where is your `winsorize` function coming from?

Comment: @mozway it's coming from `scipy` which is why i added that tag (see [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.winsorize.html))

Comment: It is from scipy.stats.mstats import winsorize

Comment: which value would you expect in place of inf in the output?

Comment: @newcomer: you just need to use `clip` built in function in Pandas. See my solution below. It is much faster than using `winsorize` and it can handle `inf` values

Answer (score 1):

You can't really handle infinite values in a quantile calculation.

I see two options.

You want to consider the infinite as NaN:

```
df_inf['variable'] = winsorize(df_inf['variable'].where(np.isfinite(df_inf['variable'])),
                               limits=[0.05, 0.05], inclusive=(True, True),
                               inplace=False, axis=None, nan_policy='omit')
```

Output:

```
         Date  variable
0  2016-05-10  0.849110
1  2016-05-11  0.404138
2  2016-05-12  0.213768
3  2016-05-13  0.072863
4  2016-05-14  0.572142
5  2016-05-15  0.353900
6  2016-05-16  0.010530
7  2016-05-17  0.013326
8  2016-05-18  0.920732
9  2016-05-19       NaN
10 2016-05-20  0.572637
11 2016-05-21  0.835157
```

You want to keep the Inf but assign an arbitrary high value:

```
df_inf['variable'] = winsorize(df_inf['variable'].clip(upper=1000),
                               limits=[0.05, 0.05], inclusive=(True, True),
                               inplace=False, axis=None, nan_policy='omit')
```

Output:

```
         Date     variable
0  2016-05-10     0.849110
1  2016-05-11     0.404138
2  2016-05-12     0.213768
3  2016-05-13     0.072863
4  2016-05-14     0.572142
5  2016-05-15     0.353900
6  2016-05-16     0.010530
7  2016-05-17     0.013326
8  2016-05-18     0.920732
9  2016-05-19  1000.000000
10 2016-05-20     0.572637
11 2016-05-21     0.835157
```

Comment: Ok, I like the first option best. But just wondering why nothing happened to the lower 5% of the values...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in function `clip` in pandas. I give you the general solution for even if you need to winsorize with `groupby`. This works well even with `np.inf`

**Sample data:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a']*100+['b']*100,
                   'val':np.random.randint(1,100,200)})
df.iloc[[0,1],1]=np.inf
df.iloc[[2,3],1]=-np.inf
```

**Winsorize**

```
# wpct
wpct = 0.01 # threshold to winsorize at 1% and 99%. Change to any value you like

# winsorize
df['valws'] = df.groupby('name')['val'].apply(lambda g: g.clip(lower=g.quantile(wpct), upper=g.quantile(1-wpct)))
```

Comment: Why you have to set `0, 1, 2, 3` to `inf`?

Comment: @PTQuoc: just an illustration how `clip` can handle `inf`

Comment: Sr my bad, your code is good